# How to customize a ListView like this in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listbox, styles

I'm new to app dev. I am now stuck in the design of my app. This item is an item like a bulletin board. Just do not know which way is the right way to design my data in this style below? I had no idea whether to use the `DATAGRIDVIEW` OR `LISTVIEW`/`LISTBOX`?

[image]

Hope to get some idea from you guys

Comment: Not sure if this is the best answer for you, but have you considered a WPF User Control? If your item has much view logic or business logic to it (which ideally should be in a separate class) it's easier to handle/abstract it that way.

Comment: thanks. Do I have to customize one or is there any reference design? Thanks

Comment: If you want to use a WPF User Control you make one from scratch. It works just like a window (XAML for the view, and C# for the logic), except it can't exist on its own. Once you create it, you can then put a bunch of them in, say, a StackPanel in a Window.

Answer (score 0):

As Nex said, you are better off making the design shown in your picture as a usercontrol and after you do that use a ListView with a data template like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="mylistview">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            //a Panel container (i.e stackpanel, wrappanel)
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            //Your usercontrol
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

and of course you will need to use data binding to show your data.

Comment: Thanks. I am now inspired.